# Understanding TO_CHAR to convert dates in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, to-char

I have an oracle data problem which i would like to understand.

So below are some queries which i executed and on comments are the outputs.

```
SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL; --19-DEC-17 
SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'DD/MM/YYYY') FROM DUAL; -- 19/12/2017
SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'MM/DD/YYYY') FROM DUAL; -- 12/19/2017
```

My question is what kind of date format does the to_char method expecting as the first parameter ? is there a default date format we need to pass?

So i tried this below query as well which throws an error. 
if some expert could explain me on how the to_char is working, it would be great.

```
SELECT TO_CHAR('19/12/2017','DD/MM/YYYY') FROM DUAL;

ORA-01722: invalid number
01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
*Cause:    The specified number was invalid.
*Action:   Specify a valid number.
```

Comment: Format? It's expecting something that is already a date, thus format is as irrelevant as format in numbers.

Comment: to_char just converts the date to any format you pass as its second parameter.  as in your example  1. 'DD/MM/YYYY' -  output in same format 19/12/2017

Comment: @Nikhil what i understand is that the first parameter has to be a date object ? am i right ? IF we try this TO_CHAR('19/12/2017','DD/MM/YYYY')  it fails

Comment: @HudhaifaYoosuf - You can upvote the answers also which helped you. Cheers:)

Comment: After trying to get the year using EXTRACT with a known date, failing totally at it and no matter how much I tried to convert it with TO_CHAR() first, I finally did this and it works: TO_CHAR(INSTALLED_DT, 'YYYY') AS INSTALLED_YEAR.  Bingo, to hell with the complex solutions it takes forever to get working :) Puck 'em, LOL.

Comment: Use TO_DATE not TO_CHAR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your query, what you're using is a string value. Instead, if you want to display using TO_CHAR(), you need to use a datetime type string. In your case, '19/12/2017' is a pure string. Please convert it into date type using TO_DATE() function.

```
SELECT TO_CHAR('19/12/2017','DD/MM/YYYY') FROM DUAL;  // error
```

Quoting from the [Oracle Docs for TO_CHAR (datetime)](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions180.htm):

> **TO_CHAR (datetime)** converts a datetime or interval value of DATE,
>   TIMESTAMP, TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE, or TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE
>   datatype to a value of VARCHAR2 datatype in the format specified by
>   the date format fmt. If you omit fmt, then date is converted to a
>   VARCHAR2 value as follows:
>
> DATE values are converted to values in the default date format.
>
> TIMESTAMP and TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE values are converted to
>   values in the default timestamp format.
>
> TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE values are converted to values in the default
>   timestamp with time zone format.

Similarly, the function TO_CHAR() accepts numbers as well.

Quoting from the [Oracle Docs for TO_CHAR (number)](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions181.htm):

> **TO_CHAR (number)** converts n to a value of VARCHAR2 datatype, using the
>   optional number format fmt. The value n can be of type NUMBER,
>   BINARY_FLOAT, or BINARY_DOUBLE. If you omit fmt, then n is converted
>   to a VARCHAR2 value exactly long enough to hold its significant
>   digits.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned above, '19/12/2017' is already a string so you cannot use it with to_char.  If you want to do this for testing you would first need to convert '19/12/2017' to a date format using to_date('19/12/2017','DD/MM/YYYY') and then you could use to_char to convert back to a character format.   For example, to_char(to_date('19/12/2017','DD/MM/YYYY'),'Mon DD, YYYY') will return 'Dec 19, 2017'.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
SELECT TO_CHAR('19/12/2017','DD/MM/YYYY') FROM DUAL;
```

doesn't make sense. '19/12/2017' is a string, so there's no use in converting it to yet another string (as you used TO_CHAR), not to mention format mask.

It would be OK if you used TO_DATE in this statement, which says that you want to convert a string '19/12/2017' into a date value, using 'dd/mm/yyyy' format mask.

That's what you did in the first part of your message. SYSDATE is a function which returns DATE data type value, so you applied TO_CHAR to it in order to display it in a format you want. Have a look at Format Models, here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm