# Inject character to date column

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I have a date column.

```
select RETAIL_ACQUISITION_DTTM from XXXXX.TABLE_2348

13/07/2018
```

I want to select the value as such it returns as below,

```
2018-07-13T00:00:00
```

so it has to display the date as YYYY-MM-DD with T and then HH24:MI:SS

Comment: and what have you tried? hint: to_char

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding TO\_CHAR to convert dates in oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47891506/understanding-to-char-to-convert-dates-in-oracle)

Comment: select to_char(to_date(RETAIL_ACQUISITION_DTTM, 'YYYY-MM-DD-HH24:MI:SS'),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as RETAIL_ACQUISITION_DTTM from XXXXX.TABLE_2348

Comment: The above returned with  -- 0013-07-18 00:00:00

Comment: The year should have been 2018-07-13 and not 0013-07-18

Comment: As I ave mentioned I need the letter T in between the date and time

Comment: eg: YYYY-MM-DD**T**HH24:MI:SS

Comment: What data type is the column - is it actually a string, or is it (as the name and contents suggest) actually a date that your client is just showing formatted as DD/MM/YYYY?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace sysdate with your column name if its date type.

Using Single to_char:

```
select to_char(sysdate,'--YYYY-MM-DD"T"hh24:mi:ss') from dual;
```

Using two to_char and concatenation for simplification.

```
select to_char(sysdate,'--'||'YYYY-MM-DD')||'T'||to_char(sysdate,'hh24:mi:ss') from dual; -- 13/07/2018
select '--'||to_char(sysdate,'YYYY-MM-DD')||'T'||to_char(sysdate,'hh24:mi:ss') from dual; -- 13/07/2018
```

Comment: select to_char(RETAIL_ACQUISITION_DTTM, 'YYYY-MM-DD')||'T'||to_char(RETAIL_ACQUISITION_DTTM,'hh24:mi:ss') from XXXXX.TABLE_2348

Comment: A bit elaborate perhaps, when you can just include a `"T"` in the format mask.

Comment: Hi @WilliamRobertson, I just used simple concatenation operator and formatting time and date part separately. Please let me know if its not what you are asking

Comment: I just mean you do two `to_char`s and concatenate the results, when you could use one and no concatenation.

Answer (score 4):

You need to convert your string (why is it stored as a string?) to a date using a format model that matches the actual string value:

```
to_date(RETAIL_ACQUISITION_DTTM, 'DD/MM/YYYY')
```

Having that format model wrong is why you get the 0013 year in your result.

Then you can convert that date back to a string with `to_char()`, and you can embed the fixed `T` as a character literal with double quotes, using a format model like `'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS'`:

```
with TABLE_2348 (RETAIL_ACQUISITION_DTTM) as (
  select '13/07/2018' from dual
)
select to_char(to_date(RETAIL_ACQUISITION_DTTM, 'DD/MM/YYYY'),
  'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS') as RETAIL_ACQUISITION_DTTM
from XXXXX.TABLE_2348;

RETAIL_ACQUISITION_
-------------------
2018-07-13T00:00:00
```

You could also just ignore that it is a date and use string manipulation:

```
with TABLE_2348 (RETAIL_ACQUISITION_DTTM) as (
  select '13/07/2018' from dual
)
select substr(RETAIL_ACQUISITION_DTTM, 7, 4)
  || '-' || substr(RETAIL_ACQUISITION_DTTM, 4, 2)
  || '-' ||substr(RETAIL_ACQUISITION_DTTM, 1, 2)
  || 'T00:00:00' as RETAIL_ACQUISITION_DTTM
from XXXXX.TABLE_2348;

RETAIL_ACQUISITION_
-------------------
2018-07-13T00:00:00
```

---

If the column is actually a date rather than a string then you are doing unnecessary conversions, including implicit ones which rely on your NLS settings, and you are losing the original time from the value if it was not midnight anyway:

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'DD-MON-RR';

with TABLE_2348 (RETAIL_ACQUISITION_DTTM) as (
  select to_date('2018-07-13 12:34:56', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') from dual
)
select to_char(to_date(RETAIL_ACQUISITION_DTTM, 'YYYY-MM-DD-HH24:MI:SS'),
  'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as RETAIL_ACQUISITION_DTTM from XXXXX.TABLE_2348;

RETAIL_ACQUISITION_
-------------------
0013-07-20 18:00:00
```

That is really doing:

```
to_char(
  to_date(
    to_char(
      RETAIL_ACQUISITION_DTTM,
      'DD-MON-RR'),     ---- from your session NLS_DATE_FORMAT setting
    'YYYY-MM-DD-HH24:MI:SS'),
  'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

If you skip to extra steps you can just format the date directly:

```
with TABLE_2348 (RETAIL_ACQUISITION_DTTM) as (
  select to_date('2018-07-13 12:34:56', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') from dual
)
select to_char(RETAIL_ACQUISITION_DTTM,
  'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS') as RETAIL_ACQUISITION_DTTM
from XXXXX.TABLE_2348;

RETAIL_ACQUISITION_
-------------------
2018-07-13T12:34:56
```

which also doesn't rely on your NLS settings, so won't break in interesting ways if it's run in another session with different settings.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, It is a date column. I followed the 1st method you had said and got the below

Comment: select to_char(to_date(RETAIL_ACQUISITION_DTTM, 'DD/MM/YYYY'), 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS') as RETAIL_ACQUISITION_DTTM from XXXXX.TABLE_2348

Comment: as 0018-07-13T00:00:00

Comment: tried the 2nd method and it proved something diff as well

Comment: select substr(RETAIL_ACQUISITION_DTTM, 7, 4)
  || '-' || substr(RETAIL_ACQUISITION_DTTM, 4, 2)
  || '-' ||substr(RETAIL_ACQUISITION_DTTM, 1, 2)
  || 'T00:00:00' as RETAIL_ACQUISITION_DTTM from XXXXX.TABLE_2348

Comment: Right, then your `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` is DD-MON-/YY (or RR), not DD/MM/YYYY. Either the string you showed in the question isn't what you actually see, or your client is overriding the NLS settings when it shows the date natively. Either way, read the rest of the answer and use the last query without the extra conversions.

Comment: select to_char(RETAIL_ACQUISITION_DTTM, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS') as RETAIL_ACQUISITION_DTTM
from XXXXXX.TABLE_2348;

Comment: 2018-07-13T00:00:00